# Timeline Jump Distance Change

Tags: animation, interface, add-on, customization, units

Pressing <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Up arrow</kbd>/<kbd>Down arrow</kbd> causes marker to move 10 frames in a given direction. This being in the timeline that is.

What I'd like to have it do is jump 12 frames to accommodate half second intervals.

Attempting to keep robust animations.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In User Preferences (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>U</kbd>), go to the Input section. In the search field on the right, search for `shift up arrow` (be sure to set your Filter Type from Name to Key Binding). You'll find the binding for the Frame Offset operator. If you expand the operator, you should see a Delta setting in the lower right. It's default value is 10. You can change it to 12 (or whatever other value you want).

[image]

Comment: Oh, just saw this answer.  I guessed I missed it while writing mine, sorry!

Answer (score 1):

Go to Blender's User Preferences by going to File -> User Preferences:

[image: Preferences]

And now search for "frame" in the search bar.  The first two results will be "Frame Offset".  You can adjust the "Delta" value (the change that it applies) to the desired amount.  In your case, 12.

[image: Pane]

This also works for other values, such as the left and right arrow keys, should you wish to adjust them.